# Exception connecting to a Database in Java:JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get all the column values from a Table using JDBC.

This is the code that I wrote in my main program.

```
 Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.driver" );
 String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test.com/abc_1_20121225;instance=abcd";
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"uname","pwd");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs;

  rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'MyTable'");
    while ( rs.next() ) {
         String colName = rs.getString("column_name");
                     System.out.println(colName);
      }
  conn.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
 System.err.println(e.getMessage());
```

I have added jtds.jar in my class path. I am getting this message

```
Got an exception! 
com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

Can someone tell me the exact reason for the problem?

Edit:

Adding stactrace;

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at schwab.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:15)
```

Comment: Instead of e.getMessage(), can you try with e.printStackTrace() and provide us stacktrace?

Comment: MySQL jar having a Driver class not driver class. Try it          Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ); Please give stack trace for further investigation.

Comment: Also what is the exact exception - as that gives more info than just there is an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the wrong driver.

Replace this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

With

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score 3):

`Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.driver" );`

--> If You are using mysql driver, It is Driver class not driver.

`String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test.com/abc_1_20121225;instance=abcd";`

---> Your url will point to SQL Server database.

Make sure which database you are using. If you are using MySQL, use MySQL Connector jar and driver class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

If you are using MS Sql server, Use Driver Class : `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` for `jTDS Driver` OR `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you dont have the MysQL driver on your classpath. However, if you provide full stack trace you should be able to confirm this.

However, it looks like you are using a SQLServer database so I am not sure why you are referencing the MYSQL driver?

Answer (score -1):

Download **sqljdbc4-2.0.jar** and attach with your project. It will solve your problem.

Comment: The OP is trying to load a MySQL driver, whereas the URL is a jTds URL. Adding the official SQL Server driver to the project won't solve any problems here...